# how to replace C++ text with a changing string

Tags: c++

To quickly sum up what i am doing, I need this C++ win32 dll:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
extern "C"
{
__declspec (dllexport) void __stdcall RVExtension(char *output, int outputSize,
                                                  const char *function);
}

void __stdcall RVExtension(char *output, int outputSize, const char *function)
{
strncpy_s(output, outputSize, "IT WORKS!", _TRUNCATE);
}
```

To not have "It Works!" output but rather a 20 character string of numbers symbols and letters. I know to little about C++ to do this, any ideas or hints?

Comment: *What* 20 character string?  The same string every time?  Should the string be derived from the arguments to `RVExtension`, and, if so, how?

Comment: i.e. *"I need some function that will somehow return some string of length 20"*

Comment: Ah, it needs to be different every time, random, it doesn't need to be derived from anything specific. all it needs to be is a random 20 character string output where "It works!" currently is, every time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Change into this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
extern "C"
string My_Text;
{
__declspec (dllexport) void __stdcall RVExtension(char *output, int outputSize,
                                                  const char *function);
}

void __stdcall RVExtension(char *output, int outputSize, const char *function)
{
strncpy_s(output, outputSize, My_Text.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
}
```

Now anywhere in the file call `My_Text="Type your text here";`. Example:

source_code.c:

```
void someFunction()
{
    My_Text = "A new message";
    ... the rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: Btw, If you are lucky enough to do what you want just by reading this you should go play lottery.

Comment: Yes, hehe you lost me. I guess there is a disconnected. I figured that where "It works!" is there could be a string, and that string's value is say %RANDOMNUMBERS%. so every time the dll is called the output is a different random 20 character combination